# AWS: Trigger step function state machine on s3 object creation using Event Bridge Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

I enabled notifications for Amazon EventBridge on my s3 bucket.
[image]

Then I created an EventBridge rule with the following event pattern:

```
{
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"]
    }
  },
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "source": ["aws.s3"]
}
```

Then I added my state machine as the target of this rule. I also attached an IAM role with the following policy for this event target.

```
"Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [ "states:StartExecution" ],
            "Resource": [ "arn:aws:states:*:*:stateMachine:*" ]
        }
    ]
```

Then I attached the following policy to my state machine step function as well:

```
{ 
        "Action": "events:*", 
        "Resource": "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:my-account-id:event-bus/default", 
        "Effect": "Allow" 
      }
```

After doing all of this, still my state machine is not getting invoked.
[image]

What am I missing here? How can I debug where the issue might be?

Comment: Does the EventBridge role have permission to invoke Step Functions?

Comment: @Paolo Yes the permissions were right! I'd added them in the question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if your `custom pattern` matches the event?
I think you do not need `arn` in the name.
Try with

```
{
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["my-bucket"]
    }
  },
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "source": ["aws.s3"]
}
```